# MongoDB How to sort an array of objects without using aggregate & group?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to sort an array of objects inside my modal and the only way to do it (as I saw) is the following:

```
...
const notifications = await Notification
            .aggregate([
                {$match: {to: userId}},
                {$unwind: '$messages'},
                {$sort: {'messages.createdAt':-1}},
                {$group: {
                        _id: '$_id',
                        createdAt: {$first: '$createdAt'},
                        messages: {$push: '$messages'},
                    }}
            ])
...
```

However, I am wondering if there is another way to do it. It seems that I have to do so many operations, even though all I want is to sort an array (grouping for example would make sense if I would actually change anything about the data but I dont). The only other way to do it I found was this:

```
const notifications = await Notification.findOne({to: userId}).sort({'messages.createdAt': -1})
```

but that doesnt sort my array in descending order, basically does nothing.

```
const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    to: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    messages: [{
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        body: {
            type: String
        },
        isRead: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: new Date()
        }
    }, ]
},{timestamps: true});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) operator if you have MongoDB 5.2 or above. Otherwise, you can go through the path of unwinding and grouping. Or you can modify your update operation for the `Notification model` so that it already sorts, the messages by their `createdAt`, in descending order and you don't have to perform the sorting while fetching the notification using `find` method. Something like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "notification": "Hello"
},
{
  "$push": {
    messages: {
      "$each": [
        {
          id: "4"
        }
      ],
      "$sort": {
        id: -1
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOg_Ty6Owef)

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I use it in my case - please see my link to same playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xujp_G7_rLV

Comment: Playground doesn't support all the update methods. I have updated your playground to make it work. Check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/UfOaJTZL-tO. @juliascoding

Comment: thanks, but how can I use each sort and still push my message (object) into the messages array? https://mongoplayground.net/p/_tbJP4Vh6XP

Comment: You should provide the message in `$each` array like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/ImXj_1XQCWH

Comment: Thanks a lot! just a last question: is the any drawback on saving and sorting to mongo vs only sorting it after fetching from db?

Comment: Not as such, in fact it's efficient since sorting while saving, prevents sorting again and again, while fetching.